# Parse HTML to get text for individual elements using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup, html-parsing

I need to parse the below text and create separate objects for each text. I tried a few ways to do it, but it does not provide the results in the format I need.

The text is:

```
String text = "This is start of a text&nbsp;<a href=\"https://google.com/sample\">followed by a link&nbsp;sample</a>and ending with some text."
```

Using the below code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(text);
Elements elements = document.select("*");
for(Element e : elements){
System.out.println( e.tagName() + ": " + e.text());}
```

The actual results are

```
root: This is start of a text followed by a link sampleand ending with some text.
html: This is start of a text followed by a link sampleand ending with some text.
head: 
body: This is start of a text followed by a link sampleand ending with some text.
p: This is start of a text followed by a link sampleand ending with some text.
a: followed by a link sample
```

I need to get the below results so that I can create a custom object for each of the text

```
body: This is start of a text&nbsp;
a:followed by a link&nbsp;sample
body:and ending with some text.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid returning text of all children use `e.ownText()`, but that's not enough in this case as you want to have separate `This is start of a text` and `and ending with some text.`, but `ownText()` returns it joined: `This is start of a text and ending with some text.`.
To get the list of separated texts use `e.textNodes()` and the output for body will be:

```
body: [
This is start of a text&nbsp;, and ending with some text.]
a: [followed by a link&nbsp;sample]
```

and an additional advantage is you're keeping original `&nbsp;`.
Also if you don't like redundant `html: []` and `head: []` added to your document you should use XML parser:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(text, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

To keep both text separated and `<a>` text in order try iterating recursively using: `document.childNodes()` and then `childNodes()` for every node. You can identify text nodes by checking `if (node instanceof TextNode)`.

Comment: Thanks this did help!!